# regex matching websites only with http without www

Tags: c#, .net, html, regex

I want to get all the websites from HTML code. The problem is that I have a regex which takes all the URLs but there needs to be `www` in the address. What kind of regex I need to use to get the URLs without `www` in the content?

update: The regex I am using is:

```
string anchorPattern = 
  @"(?<Protocol>\w+)://(?<Domain>[\w@][\w.:@]+)/?[\w.?=%&=\-@/$,&amp;+]*'";
```

Comment: Obligatory link: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/960195

Comment: Obligatory question:  What is the regex you have right now?

Comment: @AdamMihalcin: As long as he just wants to extract URLs it's perfectly fine to use a regex. The fact that it's a HTML document doesn't really matter since he is not looking for urls inside e.g. href attributes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add (?=www) for only urls that have www

```
@"(?<Protocol>\w+)://(?=www)(?<Domain>[\w@][\w.:@]+)/?[\w.?=%&=\-@/$,&amp;+]*"
```

or add (?!www) for no www urls

```
@"(?<Protocol>\w+)://(?!www)(?<Domain>[\w@][\w.:@]+)/?[\w.?=%&=\-@/$,&amp;+]*"
```

Answer (score 0):

One like you have, but without the part of the regex that looks like `www\.`